# How do you say “phonestheme” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word “[phonestheme](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/vorto-phonestheme.html)” appears neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro, nor in ReVo. Nor does the online PIV give any hit beginning with “fon”. So, how should “phonestheme” be rendered in Esperanto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this using the same [etymology as the original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme) ('sound' + 'perception') to make it *sonpercepto*.

Comment: I've used your answer, with attribution, and link, in my online dictionary, here: http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/vorto-phonestheme.html